# Set R's random seed with a hash

Tags: r, random

R provides a function `set.seed` to seed the RNG with an integer. The standard package `digest` can hash objects with a variety of hash algorithms, and can output an ASCII representation of the hash or a vector of raw bytes, but can't produce an integer. How can I use the hash of an arbitrary object to seed the RNG?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Setting the seed is about being able to reproduce the numbers produced by the RNG. If that is not important, then you can simply ignore setting the seed, since R will properly initialize it's RNG (system).

Comment: @RalfStubner I indeed want reproducibility. I have a function that as part of a data-setup process selects cross-validation folds, which need to be selected independently from each other in various settings (because the set of objects being assigned to folds can change), but also need to be reproducible. A clean way to arrange this would be to seed the RNG based on a hash of the relevant arguments to the function (or the set of objects to be assigned to folds, or something like that).

Comment: In that case I would try to use independent but reproducible random streams as used for parallel computation. An easy to use interface for that is provided by `rngtools::RNGseq`.

Comment: @RalfStubner Interesting. I'm not sure I understand the documentation of `RNGseq`, but it looks like I would have to know how many streams I want in advance, then decide on a scheme to map each scenario to a stream number.

Comment: Knowing the number of stream would be helpful. It should be possible to design something similar without that knowledge using the underlying `parallel::nextRNGream`, but that would be more involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `set.seed` is the only interface to seeding R's RNG. And R integers are always 32 bits, even on 64-bit machines. So we need to use a 32-bit hash. `digest` provides several 32-bit hashes, but `raw = TRUE` is ignored for all of them, so we need to do some string operations on a hex representation of the hash. Putting it all together:

```
set.seed.obj = function(x)
   {x = as.raw(as.hexmode(substring(
        digest::digest(x, algo = "xxhash32"),
        c(1, 3, 5, 7),
        c(2, 4, 6, 8))))
    x = rawConnection(x)
    set.seed(readBin(x, "int"))
    close(x)}

set.seed.obj("hello world")
print(rnorm(3))
set.seed.obj("goodbye world")
print(rnorm(3))
set.seed.obj("hello world")
print(rnorm(3))
```

Surprisingly, the first assignment to `x` is necessary: calling `rawConnection` on the `as.raw(...)` expression directly results in `Error in rawConnection…: invalid 'description' argument`. Evidently R crashes while trying to make a string representation of the argument for the connection's `description` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The interface to `set.seed()` is indeed given, and only takes an integer.  That is a design decision, and it is not a bad one:  `set.seed(123)` is easy to write down, and controlled behaviour afterwards is guaranteed.

If you actually dig deeper, there is *way more* inside the *multiple (!!)* RNGs used by R.  There are different ones, you can switch between them, and even by default you get (as I recall) different ones for uniform and normal draws.  Still, the seeding interface covers both.

And at the C level, there is a much larger (more complicated) data structure at play.

Now, my [digest](https://cran.r-project.org/package=digest) package.  It does indeed operate on arbitrary R objects returning string objects.  As such, it does not help with `set.seed()` as these characters are not integers.  But you could for example set an intermediating layer where you once again 'hash-map' these character strings to integers.

In short, I think you need to rethink your design a little.

*Edit:* By request, even if I think this is not the way to do it:

```
 R> c2i <- function(s) sum(as.integer(charToRaw(s)))
 R> c2i(digest(42))
 [1] 2332
 R> set.seed(c2i(digest(42)))
```

Comment: "But you could for example set an intermediating layer where you once again 'hash-map' these character strings to integers." — It would seem more direct to interpret the hash value itself as an integer.

Comment: We are going in circles.  `set.seed(digest(someObj))` is an still an error _because of the definition of both functions_ and does not change by wishing it was different.

Comment: I'm not expecting the call `set.seed(digest(someObj))` to magically begin working but e.g. code to interpret the bytes of `digest(someObj, raw = T)` as an integer (e.g., in the manner of Python 3's `struct.unpack`), so the result can then be fed to `set.seed`.

Comment: So write a mapper function if you need a mapper function. That is what my answer suggested.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking how to do. (Or for some alternative method to the same end, like feeding the raw bytes to some internal R function that will accept them instead of an integer.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Are you sure you don't mean `sum(as.integer(digest(..., raw = T)))` rather than  `sum(as.integer(charToRaw(digest(...))))`? Also, regarding "I think this is not the way to do it", what way would you prefer?